# Blender + ctypes = segmentation fault

Tags: add-on

I'd like to use Blender as a modeling environment for engineering stuff.
Blender = python - that is obvious, however I have plenty of functionality for my modeling written in c++ but exported as a c with extern "C".
In order to use my c++ functionality in python, I wrap it using ctypes, which works well with python2.7 and python3.5.
Generally I use my c++ (with extern "C") functionality with python and ctypes with no problems, but in Blender I have a big problem - it simply crashes when I try to get any value from my c++ shared object.
The following two pieces of code recreate the problem:

==== ==== c++ functionality (compiled as libblTest.so) ==== ====

```
#include <stdio.h>

class KBlenderTest
{
public:
   KBlenderTest(double initVal)
   {
       _val = initVal;
       printf("obj created: initVal: %g\n", _val);  // print to prove that object was created
   }

   ~KBlenderTest()
   {
       printf("obj deleted\n");
   }

  /** function that crashes Blender, but not other instances of python interpreter */
  double get_val()
   {
       return _val;
   }
private:
   double _val;
};

extern "C"
{
    KBlenderTest *KBlenderTest_init(double initVal)
    {
        return new KBlenderTest(initVal);
    }

    void KBlenderTest_del(KBlenderTest *obj)
    {
        delete obj;
    }

    double KBlenderTest_get_val(KBlenderTest *obj)
    {
        return obj->get_val();
    }
}
```

==== ==== python wrapper for ctypes (blTest.py) ==== ====

```
import ctypes as ctp

cpp = ctp.cdll.LoadLibrary("path_to_shared_lib/libblTest.so")

cpp.KBlenderTest_get_val.restype = ctp.c_double


class KBlTest(object):
    def __init__(self, initVal):
        self.obj = cpp.KBlenderTest_init(ctp.c_double(initVal))

    def get_val(self):
        return cpp.KBlenderTest_get_val(self.obj)

    def __del__(self):
        cpp.KBlenderTest_del(self.obj)


def test(initVal):
    test = KBlTest(initVal)
    print("test=", test.get_val())
```

In linux shell python I run the test with:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path_to_python_wrapper/")
import blTest

blTest.test(1.23)
```

which gives the following output:

```
obj created: initVal: 1.23
test= 1.23
obj deleted
```

Exactly the same action in Blender's python console, crashes Blender with segmentation fault. Currently I use Blender 2.79, but the situation was exactly the same with a few versions back.

Has anyone had similar problem?
The functionality I have in mind is much more complex, but I've tracked it  down to a relatively simple case.
I would be grateful for some clues how deal with this.

Best wishes,
Jerzy

Comment: Instant upvote for having made a minimal example! Have you tried building a debug build of Blender yourself, so you can see what's going on?

Comment: No, I haven't done so yet. I was hoping, that there is someone, who has successfully struggled with a case like this. I'll try do the debugging soon, but my problem is that I really need to model something soon.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to specify the arg types, e.g.

```
cpp.KBlenderTest_get_val.argtypes = (ctp.c_void_p,)
```

otherwise I think they default to `int`, which is the wrong size for a pointer on 64-bit architectures.

Also, I would recommend opening the `.so` file with its full name including version number, e.g.

```
cpp = ctp.cdll.LoadLibrary("path_to_shared_lib/libblTest.so.1")
```

This is because it is usual to increment the version suffix if/when the ABI changes in some backward-incompatible way, so you want to make sure you stay with the right version, at least until your Python wrapper gets updated to the newer version in future.